# Flatten/Compress deeply nested directories in ZSH

Tags: java, filesystems, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm working with a lot of Java projects and a standard in Java is to have the following directory structure:

```
▶ tree src
src
├── androidTest
│   └── java
│       └── com
│           └── mypackage
│               └── example
│                   └── ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt
├── main
│   ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│   ├── java
│   │   └── com
│   │       └── mypackage
│   │           └── example
│   │               └── MainActivity.kt
│   └── res
│
│
└── test
    └── java
        └── com
            └── mypackage
                └── example
                    └── ExampleUnitTest.kt
```

It's really a pain to work with that using the command line and as such, most IDE have a "flattening feature" to display the directories as `com.mypackage.example` instead of `com > mypackage > example`. [Even GitHub has this feature](https://github.com/novoid/github-tests/tree/7ecd4b58dbeaf1d4ff6dfc0f338bd03b0d522c25).

Is there a way to display some deeply nested directories like that as one level deep so that it can be access using `cd com.mypackage.example` instead of `cd java/com/mypackage/example` and go back with `cd ..` instead of `cd ../../../..` ?

I found [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/6omtk9/cd_skipping_directories_that_contain_only_a/) which might be useful, but it didn't solve my issue when I tried it out

Comment: You could write a script which traverses your directory tree and creates symlinks of the desired name for each subdirectory. If you add the directory where the symlinks reside to, into your `CDPATH`, your `cd` command would work. For going back, I would consider `cd -` (instead of `cd ..`), or use `pushd` and `popd` instead of `cd` in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a wrapper function around `cd`, like this:

```sh
cd() {
  # If we don't have exactly one argument that is a valid dir...
  if ! [[ $# -eq 1 && -d $PWD/$1 ]]; then
    # ...then just use the default behavior.
    builtin cd "$@"
    return
  fi

  # Get the absolute path of where normal `cd <arg1>` would take us.
  local dir=${${:-$PWD/$1}:A}

  # List the children of that dir.
  local -a children=( $dir/* )

  if [[ $1 == '..' ]]; then
    # Keep going up until we find a dir with more than one child.
    while [[ $#dir -gt 1 && $#children -eq 1 ]]; do
      dir=$dir:h
      children=( $dir/* )
    done
  else
    # Keep going down as long as we find exactly one child and it's a dir.
    while [[ $#children -eq 1 && -d $children ]]; do
      dir=$children
      children=( $dir/* )
    done
  fi

  # Pass the resulting path to `cd`.
  builtin cd $dir
}
```

You can use it then as follows:

```sh
% pwd
/[...]/src/main
% ls
java/  res/
% cd java
% pwd
/[...]/src/main/java/com/mypackage/example
% cd ..
% pwd
/[...]/src/main
```

Finally, if you want a flat file listing of your source tree, use this:

```sh
% print -lo **(T^F)
src/androidTest/java/com/mypackage/example/ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt
src/main/java/com/mypackage/example/MainActivity.kt
src/main/res/
src/test/java/com/mypackage/example/ExampleUnitTest.kt
```

- `print -l` lists each item on a separate line.
- `print -o` sorts the items ascending.
- `**` does recursive globbing.
- `(T)` adds file type markers (`/` for dirs, `@` for symlinks, etc.)
- `(^F)` matches anything *except* dirs with children (“Full” dirs).